# Can threading.event be used as an event in an modal operator?

Tags: python, operator

I am trying to use the event from a thread as an event in a modal operator, is this possible using the `bpy.types.Event` somehow?

Or do I have to set a timer and check if the event is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to pass it to the operator's [`modal`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.modal) method, so you can't mix both event types. Using a [`Timer`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Timer.html) is a better option.